# How to import alphavantage library in android studio

Tags: android-studio, github, alpha-vantage

I want to import this library https://github.com/patriques82/alphavantage4j in android studio.  What steps should I follow?(from scratch) Also in which build.gradle should I put repositories and dependencies?

I have an empty project. I downloaded the zip file and extracted it. I then tried to import the module but only the build.gradle file was imported.

There already existed a build.gradle file. So I renamed the build.gradle as builder.gradle and imported it.But it showed error as sync failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.** Create a new Android Project.

**2.** Open `build.gradle`.There will be two gradle builds, you will need to select the `Project` build

**3.** Add the repository information `maven{...}` to both `buildscript` and `allprojects`.

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.31'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url  "https://dl.bintray.com/patriques82/maven"
        }

    }

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url  "https://dl.bintray.com/patriques82/maven"
        }

    }
}
```

**4.** Open up the second '`build.gradle`' (Module:app) and add into `dependencies`
the following

```
implementation 'org.patriques:alphavantage4j:1.4'
```